# How to show cluster name using google_monitoring_alert_policy resource for Terraform

Tags: terraform

Looking for a way to show a cluster name on a display_name parameter into google_monitoring_alert_policy resource for Terraform. My code looks like the following

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "failedscheduling_pods_alert_policy" {
  display_name          = "More than 10 FailedScheduling pod events in 5 minutes in ${var.monitored_project_id}"
  ....
  conditions {
    display_name = "FailedScheduling pods events in cluster"
      filter          = "metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/user/failedscheduling-pods-${var.monitored_project_id}\" AND resource.type=\"k8s_pod\""
   ...
  }
  depends_on = [module.failedscheduling_count]
}

module "failedscheduling_count" {
  ...
  filter       = "resource.type=\"k8s_pod\" AND jsonPayload.reason=\"FailedScheduling\" AND resource.labels.project_id=\"${var.monitored_project_id}\""
  display_name = "FailedScheduling events in the logs"
  labels = [
    {
      key   = "Cluster"
      field = "EXTRACT(resource.labels.cluster_name)"
    },
    {
      key   = "Namespace"
      field = "EXTRACT(resource.labels.cluster_name)"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to pass the value from module.failedscheduling_count.labels."Cluster" (this is a pseudo code)?
For instance: `display_name = "More than 10 FailedScheduling pod events in 5 minutes in ${var.monitored_project_id} in cluster ${module.failedscheduling_count.labels."Cluster"}"`

Versions:
terraform ~>1.1.0
hashicorp/google 4.15.0

Comment: If the `display_name` field of `google_monitoring_alert_policy` resource accepts that big string, you can I think. But, you would need to expose `labels` via `outputs` in the module so that it can be accessed outside. Post exposure, you could access it like `${module.failedscheduling_count.labels["Cluster"]}` or `lookup(module.failedscheduling_count.labels, "Cluster", "what?")`..

Comment: @harshavmb unfortunately it doesn't work. The response is │ This object does not have an attribute named "labels".